# Is it possible to set a bounty for an old question somehow?

Tags: support, bounty

I want to try my luck and see if someone can answer this question I made about a month ago:
[Simplifying the summation $ (3^i\sqrt{n/3^i})/\log_2(n/3^i)$ from $i=0 \text{ to }k-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090509/simplifying-the-summation-3i-sqrtn-3i-log-2n-3i-from-i-0-text-to)

I thought maybe a good way to draw attention to the question would be by starting a bounty, but I came to the realization that I cannot longer do this. Is there a way to make the option be available again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course. But you need to have 75 points of reputation in order to set up a bounty.

So you're one vote away from that goal.

Comment: Oh that explains everything lol, thanks for the information.

Comment: I know it's meta, but I just wanted to let you know I downvoted the answer by accident.